# Can I make a public circle in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like to make a circle that other people can subscribe to in Google+.  For my specific example, I know a few of my friends are interested in the fantasy series *Wheel of Time* and I'd like to add them to a circle so I can update just those people on my progress in the series.  Is there any way (other than broadcasting a message to everyone and just *asking* them, then adding them manually) to make the circle public so that other people who follow me can opt in to get updates to that circle as well?

Comment: There is not (at this time) a way to create any sort of "shared" circle. It is a much requested feature.

Comment: I have seen more than one person post a public message that says "If you'd like to see my posts about X, +1 this message and I'll add you to my X Circle."

Comment: @Al Everett: Thanks for the comments.  It's a good idea to get people to +1 instead of replying.

Comment: Another couple of efforts used a public Google Spreadsheet to allow people to self-identify (as photographers, for instance) so that those self-same people could add the others in the list to their own Circle.

Answer (score 4):

A few new resources have appeared to try and address this such as ;

http://sharethiscircle.com/

> ... Google+ doesn’t provide any API, so you cannot share directly your circle. This [sharethiscircle.com] wants to be a repository for all those circles, waiting for the day Google will provide a faster way to share your circles.

And also;

http://www.recommendedusers.com/

Hope this helps.